# Protractor Testing a Non-Angular site that uses TypeScript and Webpack

Tags: typescript, testing, webpack, protractor

I'm trying to set up a TDD starter kit using the following:

- Webpack 4.26.1
- TypeScript 2.9.2
- Protractor 5.4.1
- Node 11.2.0

I have the site being served by webpack-dev-server when in development mode, and bundled to a ./dist/ folder when in production mode.

I am trying to use TypeScript for the e2e tests as well as for all configuration files (protractor.conf.ts, webpack.config.ts, etc...).

My problem is that Webpack needs to transpile the protractor.conf.ts file before protractor will recognize the config.  How do I handle this for both development mode (being served up in memory only) and production mode (being written to the file system).

**tsconfig.json**

```
{   
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": [
          "es2015",
          "dom"
        ],
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "typeRoots": [
          "node_modules/@types"
        ]   
    } 
}
```

**e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json**

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "jasminewd2",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

**protractor.conf.ts**

```
import { Config, browser } from 'protractor';

export const config: Config = {

  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/',
  specs: ['./e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'],
  framework: 'jasmine',

  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
  },

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true
  },

  onPrepare: () => {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
  },
  noGlobals: true
};
```

**webpack.config.ts**

```
 import path from 'path';
 import merge from 'webpack-merge';
 import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';

 import { wph } from './webpack.parts';

 const commonConfig = merge(<any>[
 {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    output: {
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: 'TDD Starter Kit 2.0',
        template: 'src/index.html'
      })
    ]
  },
  wph.loadTypeScript({ exclude: /node_modules/ })
]);

const productionConfig = merge(<any>[
  wph.extractInlineStyles({
    use: [ wph.autoPrefixStyles() ]
  }),
  wph.loadImages({
    options: {
      limit: 15000,
      name: '[name].[ext]'
    }
  }),
  wph.loadFonts({
    options: {
      limit: 50000
    }
  })
]);

const developmentConfig = merge(<any>[
  wph.devServer({
    host: process.env.HOST,
    port: process.env.PORT
  }),
  wph.loadInlineStyles(),
  wph.loadImages(),
  wph.loadFonts()
]);


module.exports = (mode: any) => {
  if ( mode === "production" ) {
    return merge(commonConfig, productionConfig, { mode });
  }

    return merge(commonConfig, developmentConfig, { mode });
}
```

**webpack.parts.ts**

```
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from 'mini-css-extract-plugin';

class WebpackHelper {
  loadTypeScript = ({ include, exclude }: any = {}) => ({
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          use: 'ts-loader',
          include,
          exclude
        }
      ]
    }
  })

  loadInlineStyles = ({ include, exclude }: any = {}) => ({
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          include,
          exclude,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        }
      ]
    }
  })

  extractInlineStyles = ({ include, exclude, use = [] }: any) => {
    const plugin = new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css'
    });

    return {
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.s?css$/,
            include,
            exclude,
            use: [ MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader' ].concat(use)
          }
        ]
      },
      plugins: [plugin]
    }
  }

  autoPrefixStyles = () => ({
    loader: 'postcss-loader',
    options: {
      plugins: () => [require('autoprefixer')()]
    }
  })

  loadImages = ({ include, exclude, options }: any = {}) => ({
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
          include,
          exclude,
          use: {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  })

  loadFonts = ({ include, exclude, options }: any = {})  => ({
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
          include,
          exclude,
          use: {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  })

  devServer = ({ host, port }: any = {}) => ({
    devServer: {
      stats: 'errors-only',
      host,
      port,
      open: true,
      overlay: true,
      contentBase: 'dist'
    }
  })
}

const wph = new WebpackHelper();
export { wph };
```

Comment: My best guess is that your protractor files are not included in `/dist/`  because your entrypoint does not reference them in any way. As it shouldn't. You could setup a `pretest` script that just compiles the protractor config before the tests run and reference the `conf.js` in your test script instead. You can see an example of something similar being done [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/exampleTypescript/package.json).

Comment: If there isn't any particular reason that you NEED the protractor config to be in TypeScript it would be easier to just use a `.js`. I write all my test scripts, page objects, helper classes in TypeScript and just keep the config itself as a `.js`. It works perfectly. I have everything configured so that I can run tests against my local dev environment or against any other environment such as QA, staging, prod. Sounds like the way I run my tests is very similar to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @tehbeardedone Thanks for the response...  I'm fine with leaving the protractor config in JavaScript... All I'm trying to do is to avoid having to run the site first and then run the protractor tests... Ideally, when I run the protractor tests, webpack would do it's thing first and then the tests would run...

Comment: Yeah, I understand, so what you can do is add a `pretest` script that runs your dev server and then a `test` script that starts up protractor. That will make it so that when you run `npm run <yourTestScript>` it will run the `pretest` script first and when that command has completed it will run your test script.  Although, I'm not sure how that will work with `webpack-dev-server` because the `pre` script needs to exit before the `test` script can run.